# How I can solve this Error when trying to launch WebOS TV emulator?

Tags: virtualbox, emulation, webos

I am unable to launch webOS TV emulator. Always getting below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay1Uz.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Downgrade* or *Update* Virtualbox version from your computer. I had a similar problem and what I did was to downgrade VirtualBox edition.